# Calling vectorized functions within vectorized functions

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

I am working on writing scoring code for a series of cognitive tests that are administered across batteries. In the example below, I have a dummy test called SHAPES_v1, but in my application, there are many different tests with many different versions. I am trying to vectorize my functions, both by using sapply() and Vectorize(), but the output (`scored_battery_1`) does not match what I am trying to achieve (`desired_output`). When I run the individual calls within each function on an example item, everything works, so I am pretty sure my vectorization is failing. I have Vectorize() implemented, and the sapply() commented out. The Vectorize() method contains the correct output, but still has the initial variables, and is a nested list instead of a data frame. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
library('dplyr')

battery_1 <- data.frame(PID=paste0('PID', 1:5), SHAPES_v1_QID1_RESP=c(rep(4, 3),
  rep(2, 2)), SHAPES_v1_QID2_RESP=c(rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2)),
  LETTERS_v1_QID1_RESP=c(rep(5, 3), rep(2, 2)),
  LETTERS_v1_QID2_RESP=c(rep(5, 1), rep(6, 4)))

SHAPES_v1 <- data.frame(QID=1:2, CorrectResponse=c(4, 3))

LETTERS_v1 <- data.frame(QID=1:2, CorrectResponse=c(5, 6))

########### Simplify names
simpNames <- function(i, varnames) {
  return(paste(varnames[[i]][1], varnames[[i]][2], sep='_'))
}
simpNames <- Vectorize(simpNames, vectorize.args='i', SIMPLIFY=TRUE)

########### Score a specific item
scoreItem <- function(battery, answers, item, num) {
  corrItem <- gsub('RESP', 'CORR', item)
  ans <- answers[answers$QID == num, 'CorrectResponse']
  battery <- battery %>% mutate_at( .funs = funs(ifelse(. == ans,
                            yes = 1, no = 0)), .vars = item)
  names(battery)[names(battery) == item] <- corrItem
  return(battery)
}
scoreItem <- Vectorize(scoreItem, vectorize.args=c('item', 'num'), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

########### Score a specific test
scoreTest <- function(battery, test) {
  if (exists(test) & length(grep('DISC', test)) == 0) {
    answers <- get(test)

    # List items
    items <- paste0(test, '_', 'QID', answers$QID, '_RESP')
    nums <- answers$QID

    # Score items
    battery <- scoreItem(battery, answers, items, nums)
    #battery <- sapply(1:length(nums), function(i) scoreItem(battery, answers, items[i], nums[i]))
  } else {
    print(paste('Answer key does not exist for', test))
  }
  return(battery)
}
scoreTest <- Vectorize(scoreTest, vectorize.args=c('test'), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

########### Score the whole battery
score <- function(battery) {
  varnames <- names(battery)[!(names(battery) %in% grep('PID', names(battery), value=TRUE))]
  varnames <- strsplit(varnames, '_')
  varnames <- simpNames(1:length(varnames), varnames)
  tests <- unique(varnames)

  # Score a specific test
  battery <- scoreTest(battery, tests)
  #battery <- sapply(1:length(tests), function(i) scoreTest(battery, tests[i]))

  return(battery)
}

#################### Score the batteries ####################
scored_battery_1 <- score(battery_1)
scored_battery_1

####################### Desired Output ######################
desired_output <- data.frame(PID=paste0('PID', 1:5), SHAPES_v1_QID1_CORR=c(rep(1, 3),
  rep(0, 2)), SHAPES_v1_QID2_CORR=c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 2)),
  LETTERS_v1_QID1_CORR=c(rep(1, 3), rep(0, 2)),
  LETTERS_v1_QID2_CORR=c(rep(0, 1), rep(1, 4)))
desired_output
```

Comment: not knowing much about `Vectorize`, it seems to me that it is trying to return you a list of results calculated while simultaneously looping over the variables you declare "vector-inputs" in `vectorize.args` (items, nums) and treating the other inputs (battery, answers) as one-dimensional params. While your function `simpNames` returns simple strings that can easily be coerced into a character-vector, `scoreItem` returns a dataframe in each such "iteration" and thus you get a list of those df's. [... contd. in next comment :) ]

Comment: [...] The way that you are trying to solve your problem above (looping over the items of a battery, scoring for each the recorded vs. correct answers), you are calculating a full vector of scores in each step (which you're getting to by that mutate_at) and you keep the overhead of the dataframe as well. If you really wanted to stick to that approach, I'd say you could return only the column that is the actual score (still receiving a list of vectors) and then col-bind the "PID" column and those listed vectors together. But at that point again, I think we're deep in overcomplication territory

Comment: after all, I think you're using vectorization where you don't really get added value. Technically, you're nesting two loops to score a given battery. 1) looping over tests (like "SHAPES_V1") that you have answers stored for in separate df's; 2) looping over the test-items belonging to the current test. First loop basically just helps you to load answers from the correct df. Then, within the second loop, vectorization helps you to score all recorded responses to that test-item (a vector in the df) against your correct result - and for that you're already using the vectorized `ifelse` function

Comment: Thanks! Got my original code working now, but I definitely prefer your solution. Just wanted to figure out how to fix my initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I feel you're overcomplicating a few things.
I've taken a stab at accomplishing the same output you are describing. Let me know whether the following works for you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

score <- function(battery) {
  battery %>%
    pivot_longer(-PID, names_to = 'response_id', values_to = 'response_value') %>%
    mutate(
      test_name = str_extract(response_id, '^[^_]+_[^_]+(?=_)'),
      QID = as.integer(str_extract(response_id, '(?<=QID)\\d+(?=_)'))
    ) %>%
    filter(test_name %in% ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)) %>%
    split(f = .$test_name) %>%
    imap(.f = function(test_results, test_name){
      test_results %>%
        left_join(get(test_name), by = 'QID') %>%
        filter(!is.na(CorrectResponse)) %>%
        mutate(
          is_correct = as.integer(response_value == CorrectResponse)
        )
    }) %>%
    do.call(bind_rows, .) %>%
    select(PID, response_id, is_correct) %>%
    spread(key = response_id, value = is_correct)
}
```

This is essentially doing the following:

1. pivot the response columns into a rowwise representation with `pivot_longer`, leaving the `PID` column in place
2. extract the `test_name` and `QID`, which I see you need for scoring
3. filter for only tests where we have the responses loaded
4. split the dataframe into a list, so we can ...
5. ... left join the correct response df onto each chunk, then score the test
6. rejoin the dataframes into once
7. select only the `PID` column, the original column name and our score
8. spread those out again into a column format

Tada :)

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you. Just starting to push myself to use dplyr. Your code clearly illustrates the many benefits.

Comment: It is definitely a solution to my problem, but it would be useful for my own edification (and hopefully others) to know what is failing in my original code. Should I still click the gray check?

Comment: // moved comments to your original solution to that actual post